# C#: overhead in having unused variables in an object

Tags: c#, oop

Using C#, is there any overhead in having one larger object containing a whole lot of string variables - half of which are never used in the same instance, instead of 2 objects containing half the number of string variables in which all variables will be used in all instances?

My question might actually be: what overheads are there in having large numbers of empty string variables in objects?   I'm talking about 20 unused string variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miniscule. Don't even sweat about it.

That being said, it's most probably a bad idea from the design standpoint.

Answer (score 6):

20 unused string variables will probably waste either 80 or 160 bytes per instance, depending on whether you're on a 32 or 64-bit CLR. The value of each field would be a reference, which is why it depends on the CLR. (There *may* be more wastage due to padding; it depends on the details of the object.)

Whether or not this is significant will depend on how much you use these objects - obviously the more space you take, the harder the garbage collector will have to work, and the more memory your app will take. If you have a million of these objects "live" at any one point, they'll be wasting about 80 or 160MB. Is that significant? It depends on your situation.

Comment: Sure about 80 bytes for 20 strings on 32bit? Here someone said about additional 20 bytes per instance: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html#memory

Comment: @Kamarey: That's talking about *instances* of strings. An unused string variable will typically hold a null reference, not a reference to a newly-created-but-empty string. (I can't tell whether you were making a joke or not, but you know I wrote that article, right?)

Comment: Yep, I know you wrote it. Just missed that talked about null references.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in .NET are [*interned*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx), meaning that there would only be one instance of a unique string in the whole app. The only overhead would be a reference to that string(essentially a pointer) and it is very small to worry about. **Edit** As Jon commented, strings are only interned if they are a string literal ie `var str = "literal";`, but they can easily be interned manually if required, as shown in the MSDN link.

Don't structure your classes around potentially saving a few bytes, make your classes as readable and easy to use as possible. The runtime is pretty smart and will take care of runtime performance for you.

Comment: You can have multiple instances of an equal string in .NET very easily. Strings are only interned if they are string *literals* or they're *explicitly* interned in code. However, in this case the space required by actual string objects is irrelevant, given that these string variables won't be used (so will have a value of `null` by default).

Comment: @Jon: they might be String.Empty

Comment: @Craig: Only if you explicitly set them that way - and in that case they'll all be referring to the same empty string, which would have been initialized anyway. In other words, there'd be no extra cost beyond what I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Fyodor is right, in my opinion.
The point is probably not overhead, but if having a lot of empty string is truly useful for your elaboration-flow or only a bad-design problem.
In this second case you need to consider **your** personal overhead in maintening a so bulky code.